# Evaluate $\int(3x\cdot\ln2x)dx$

Tags: integration

Evaluate

> $$\int(3x\cdot\ln2x)dx$$

Comment: just use integration by part

Comment: If you plan to participate in the community, learning to use [MathJax](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and $\LaTeX$ to post mathematical expressions will be a useful skill.

Comment: Hint: if the integrand in in form of a product, you may want to consider integration by part method. The method require you to find the derivative of one part and the antiderivative of the other part, and you will notice that finding antiderivative of $\ln$ is hard but derivative is easy, and both derivative and antiderivative of $ax^n$, $n \neq -1$ are easy to find.

Answer (score 2):

> $$\int(3x\cdot\ln2x)dx$$

By parts: $\color{gray}{f=\ln(2x),df=\frac{1}{x}dx,g=\frac{x^2}{2},dg=xdx}$

$$=\frac 3 2 x^2 \ln(2x)-\frac 3 2 \int x dx$$

$$=\frac 3 2 x^2 \ln(2x)-\frac {3x^2} {4} +C$$

$$\boxed{\color{blue}{=\frac 3 4 x^2 (2\ln(2x)-1)+C}}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\int (3x\cdot \ln2x).dx=\ln 2x\int3x.dx-\int((\ln 2x)'(\int 3x.dx)).dx=\frac{3}{2}x^2\ln 2x-\int3x.dx=\frac{3}{2}x^2\ln2x-\frac{3}{2}x^2+C$